# Proving a function is not regulated

Tags: real-analysis

I'm struggling to show that the function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-x}  &   0 \leq x <1\\1 &  x = 1\end{cases}  $$

is not regulated. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean regulated as "uniform limit of step functions"? If yes, then you should convince yourself that the uniform limit of bounded functions is bounded and $f$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

The point $x=1$ does not have a left-limit within $\mathbb{R}$, and is thus not a regulated function. (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function )

Intuitively, this is saying that if you have a genuinely diverging point in your function, superficially removing that point only is not going to fix it to become regulated. It is still not bounded.